# Permittivity measurement using open-ended coaxial probe

Tags: coax, vna, coaxial

I am trying to understand how the complex permittivity of liquids can be measured using an open-ended coaxial probe.
For this kind of measurement, we put a open-ended coaxial line into the liquid under test, and using a VNA, the reflection coefficient is determined and from this, the permittivity can be found.

The load impedance at the end of the coax is
$$Z = \frac{1}{j\,\omega\left( C_0\,\epsilon_r + C_f \right)} $$
where \$C_0\$ is the capacitance of the open-end of the coax probe, and \$C_f\$ is the fringing capacitance.
How is it possible to find \$C_0\$ and \$C_f\$ from the measurement of open, short and a known dielectric?
(I got this formula from here: https://stacks.cdc.gov/view/cdc/10047/cdc_10047_DS1.pdf)

A one-port measurement on a VNA has 3 error terms (directivity, tracking and match), so we need to perform 3 independent measurements for the calibration of the VNA. But in this case, we have two additional unknowns, \$C_0\$ and \$C_f\$. So one would expect it is required to perform at least 5 independent measurements for a calibration.

So I assume that the manufacturer of a dielectric measurement kit has a model of the coaxial probe which provides the values of \$C_0\$ and \$C_f\$. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Have you fully read the document? It tells you that an iterative technique is performed using materials with a known complex dielectric constant. This means that many measurements are made and more than 5 in all likelihood.

Comment: yes, I have read the full document and I also saw this sentence. However, in an old HP application note, there is a description of a "dielectric measurement kit", and they claim that they can calibrate their coaxial probe using only 3 measurements - open, short and distilled water. But they don't describe how it works.

Comment: I wonder why they didn’t mention that the open circuit measurements of a 1/2 wave at 30 cm air coax would cause a standing wave at the 450 resonance due to calibration limitations